# Number of integers less than $20000$ that contain digits $4$ or $7$ or both

Tags: combinatorics

What's the best way of finding the number of positive integers less than $20000$ that contain the digits $4$ or $7$ or both?

Comment: I assume you mean the number of positive integers less than $20000$, correct?

Comment: This is a straightforward application of inclusion-exclusion and multiplication principle.  Where did you get stuck?  Can you find the number of positive integers less than $20000$ that contain a $4$ (*ignoring any requirements about sevens*)?

Comment: Alternatively, can you count the number of positive integers which contain *neither* a $4$ nor a $7$?

Answer (score 4):

As @JMoravitz mentioned, a better strategy is to count the number of integers containing neither a $4$ nor a $7$.

We can split this into the following cases: the ten-thousands digit is $0$, and the ten-thousands digit is $1$.

In each case, the number would be equal to $8^4=4096$ (any digit but $4$ or $7$) for each space.

So that means $8191$ integers from $1$ to $19999$ don't have a $4$ or a $7$ (notice I subtracted $1$ to account for $00000$ which isn't positive.)

So our answer is $11808$ numbers.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:*** Do not be afraid to brute force this problem! Between $0-9$: $2$ Numbers. $(4, 7)$. Without loss of generality for $10-19,20-29$ there will also be $2$ for each set $(14,17), (24,27)$ respectively. Now for $40-49$ there will be $10.$ Now for $50-59$ there will be $2$. $60-69$ another $2$. Now for $70-79$ there will be another $10$. $80-89$, again $2$. $90-99$ again $2$. Do you spot the pattern?

Comment: that's really tough starting from 3 digits

Comment: @BarryChau Not too tough my friend. We apply this same principle for two digits. For example $100-200$ I know that I have two sections that contain the bulk of the contribution $140-149$ and $170-179$. Then all I have to do is apply the two digit rules and say "there are only $2$ in between $100-109,110-119\dots$" and so forth.